# Not visible cells in table view get overridden

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have made a form by code to sign up within the application but if I scroll up and down the cells which are not visible get overridden with the setup of other cells... Has anyone experienced something like that? I'm pretty sure that I'm missing out on some configuration but I don't know which.

Here is my code.
Its a lot of code....sorry. But I really don't know where to start

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return 4;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        return 5;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 3;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Perönliche Informationen";
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return @"Anschrift";
    } else  {
        return @"myClassico Profil";
    }

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        if ([indexPath row] == 3) {
            return 210;
        } else {
            return 44;
        }
    }


    else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            return 80;
        } else if ([indexPath row] == 3) {
            return 210;
        } else {
            return 44;
        }
    }


    else if ([indexPath section] == 2) {
        return 44;
    }


    else {
        return 44;
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"anmeldenCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            UISegmentedControl *gender = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Frau", @"Herr", nil]];
            gender.frame = CGRectMake(99, 8, 124, 28);
            gender.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:gender];


        } else if ([indexPath row] == 1) {
            UITextField *vorname = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 44)];
            vorname.placeholder = @"Vorname";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:vorname];
        } else if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
            UITextField *nachname = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 300, 44)];
            nachname.placeholder = @"Nachname";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:nachname];
        } else {

            //Code below is backup code in case someone really dislikes the UIDatePicker. Code is fully functional.
            /*
            UITextField *gebTag = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 80, 44)];
            UITextField *gebMonat = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(108, 0, 100, 44)];
            UITextField *gebJahr = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(216, 0, 100, 44)];

            gebTag.placeholder = @"TT";
            gebMonat.placeholder = @"MM";
            gebJahr.placeholder = @"JJ";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:gebTag];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:gebMonat];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:gebJahr];*/

            UILabel *gebLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 50)];
            gebLabel.text = @"Geburtsdatum";

            UIDatePicker *gender = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 30, 320, 180)];


            [cell.contentView addSubview:gender];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:gebLabel];
        } //ENDE SECTION 1 (INFORMATIONEN ZUR PERSON)

    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            UITextField *adresseStrasse = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            adresseStrasse.placeholder = @"Straße";

            UITextField *adresseHNR = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 30, 120, 44)];
            adresseHNR.textAlignment = 2;
            adresseHNR.placeholder = @"Hausnummer";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:adresseStrasse];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:adresseHNR];
        } else if ([indexPath row] == 1) {
            UITextField *adresseZusatz = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            adresseZusatz.placeholder = @"Adresszusatz (optional)";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:adresseZusatz];
        } else if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
            UITextField *adressePLZ = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 100, 44)];
            adressePLZ.placeholder = @"PLZ";

            UITextField *adresseOrt = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 0, 170, 44)];
            adresseOrt.placeholder = @"Ort";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:adressePLZ];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:adresseOrt];
        } else  {

            UILabel *land = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 150, 20)];
            land.text = @"Land";

            länderPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 300, 180)];
            [länderPicker setDelegate:self];
            array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [array addObject:@"Deutschland"];
            [array addObject:@"Österreich"];
            [array addObject:@"Schweiz"];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:land];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:länderPicker];

        } //ENDE SECTION 2 (ADRESSEN INFORMATIONEN)
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 2){
        if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
            UITextField *email = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            email.placeholder = @"E-Mail";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:email];
        } else if ([indexPath row] == 1) {
            UITextField *telefon = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            telefon.placeholder = @"Telefon";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:telefon];
        } else if ([indexPath row] == 2) {
            UITextField *mtelefon = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            mtelefon.placeholder = @"Mobiltelefon (optional)";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:mtelefon];
        } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
            UITextField *passwort = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            passwort.placeholder = @"Passwort";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:passwort];
        } else {
            UITextField *passwortWiederholung = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, 44)];
            passwortWiederholung.placeholder = @"Passwort wiederholen";

            [cell.contentView addSubview:passwortWiederholung];
        } //ENDE SECTION 3 (MYCLASSICO ACCOUNT INFORMATIONEN)
    }


    return cell;
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [array count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [array objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different identifier for cells:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"anmeldenCell";
```

or prepare reset function for them.

Your problem is that cells are reused between sections. You are adding subview here [cell.contentView addSubview:gender]; and you never remove it - so it will be added several times to the same cell + the cell with this view will be used in other sections as well.

Best approach will be to prepare custom cell per section and use different CellIdentifier for them. Also when you reuse them assing a view to it's properly instead of adding subview several times.

BTW. use enumerations for sections to increase readability, instead of 1,2,3,4 use kSectionMyProfile, etc...

Comment: But shouldn't that be handeled by dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier: ?

Comment: It is handled by that - but you are treating all your different cells as same cell  if you are using same identifier for them - and you're not getting cells that were used before. Just think about it: you addSubview to a cell - you never remove it. dequeue will return you the same cell again - and you addSubview again to it - each time it goes through that function.

Comment: The simplest solution for you will be to create identifier per section/row. But it's not really optimal if you have them in that count as I see in your code. You can also take a look at - (void)prepareForReuse; method - I would suggest to add your custom views to 1 container - and remove container within that function - with that you can keep your code as you have and use 1 identifier. Than it's just one custom class handling your TableViewCell to implement - which might be good enough solution for you.